# How to save an HTML file in Iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I want to check a page in Safari on IPhone. I have it in my mail box and want to save it and then open it in browser. But I cannot find any option to save this file in Iphone. I found a way to do the same thing on my Android phone by typing 'file://localhost/sdcard' in Chrome browser and then open the html file. Is there a similar way to save and view a file on Iphone? Please help!

Comment: You can refer this page http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38944/can-i-save-an-html-file-to-my-iphone-and-open-in-safari

Answer (score 1):

If the devices are on the same *friendly* WiFi network, spin up a Python server from terminal (in the directory containing the html file): `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` Then, get computer's local ip using `ifconfig`. 
On the iPhone, would then go to `http://<<computer's local ip>>:8000` for `index.html` or `http://<<computer's local ip>>:8000/<<filename>>.html` for any other file.

Examples:

`http://192.168.1.2:8000/`

`http://192.168.1.2:8000/notindex.html`

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is opened on your iPhone all you have to do is tap the Sharing icon, middle icon on bottom, and select 'Add to Home Screen'

If you want to load an html file that you've created on you Mac to your iPhone you'll need to do the following. From System Prefs > Sharing > Enable Web Sharing. Place the html file in your ~/Sites folder. Go the the URL listed in the Web Sharing panel from your iPhone, while on the home network, and open the html file. It will load in Mobile Safari.

If you want this to stay on your iPhone you'll need to have the page written in html5 and have a properly setup CACHE MANIFEST. This includes the appropriate tag in the html file and have the proper manifest file. Then you can follow the first step and add it to your home screen and always have it on your iPhone.

Comment: "Add to Home Screen" option isn't working. It again redirects to my gmail account and then tries to open the page. I don't want that. I want to open the saved file through Safari directly.